# how to show distance in google place autocomplete iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, uitableview, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to implement an autocomplete box. In that app, I want to show distance with a label on the left in tableview. I presume they are using the Places Autocomplete API but I don't know it show distance on the left in tableview.

[image: This picture is what I want.]

```
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        searchController?.isActive = false
        // Do something with the selected place.
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")

        self.googleMapsView.clear()

        let position: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        let marker:GMSMarker = GMSMarker(position: position)

        markerPosition = CLLocation(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude)

        marker.title = place.name
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
        marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .red)
        marker.map = self.googleMapsView

        self.googleMapsView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (place.coordinate.latitude), longitude: (place.coordinate.longitude), zoom: 17.0, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

        searchController?.searchBar.text = place.name

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // dismiss after select place
    }

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance between the given `GMSPlace` to you current device location using the function on `CLLocation` object:

```
func distance(from location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance
```

In your concrete example:

```
if let currentPosition = self.googleMapsView.myLocation {
     //returns the distance between two CLLocation objects in meters
     let distance = markerPosition.distance(from: currentPosition)
}
```

Now you can convert and format your `distance` to what ever you want.

Or you could fetch the current device location with use of the [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now, I can to calculate the distance but I can't show distance on left in the Tableview cell.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for answer. Now, I can to calculate the distance but I can't show distance on left in the Tableview cell.